# How to remove the selected value from first dropdown, so that it wont be in the second dropdown. (value direct from database) [Laravel]

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

```
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="">food 1 </label>
                        <select name="food1" class="js-example-basic-single" style="width: 100%;">
                        @foreach($items as $item)
                        <option value="{{ $item->name }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="">food 2</label>
                        <select name="food2" class="js-example-basic-single" style="width: 100%;">
                        @foreach($items as $item)
                        <option value="{{ $item->name }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    </div>
```

Tried using javascript, but its not working. Tried so many things

Updated :

public function store(Request $request)
{

```
if ($request->food1=$request->food2)
{
    echo($request->food1);
    echo($request->food2);
    echo("Wrong");
}
else
{
    $project = new Project;
    $project->food1 = $request->input('food1');
    $project->food2 = $request->input('food2');
    $project->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('status','Added Successfully');
}
```

}

Always return wrong the first one. When i tried echo, suddenly both food1 and food2 always has the same values. When i remove the if function, just use the new project and insert, it actually displays 2 different values in food1 and food2 in database.

Comment: You cant do this without some crazy Javascript functions, you will need to listen for changes and re-fetch the data again excluding the selected value. It is very heavy on loading. Why don't you just use Multiple select? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: Because the food is actually added by the users. So the food value will keep increasing in database. So if i do like multiple select it would be just that, I need it to be updated all the time.

Comment: I would recommend then to just alter the insert/update function to verify that the food does not exist for that order, if it exists it can return an error or ignore it

Comment: Does that means something like, in controller to POST. if would verify if the food1 and food2 is the same value, if same value, display error, redirect back and dont post ?

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you want to achieve?

Comment: So for ex: we have, banana, apple and orange. Those are the values pulled from db (item->name). If banana were choose in the first dropdown, I woulde like to remove it from the second dropdown.

Comment: Hey @wafi could you solve your problem or do you need some help?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want remove data from database , you can use jquery easily by below steps:

1. add id for all options in second select tags.
2. add first select id.
3. call server side by ajax and rebuild food2 dropdown again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#optionselect").change(function() {
                var values = $("#optionselect option:selected");
                var selectd = values.text();
                                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    });
                    $.post('site-address', {

                            ajax: true,
                            procedure: 'food-loader',
                            selected: selectd


                        },
                        function(data, status) {
                       //loading food2 options     

            });
        });
```

```html
<div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label for="">food 1 </label>
        <select id="optionselect" name="food1" class="js-example-basic-single" style="width: 100%;">
            @foreach ($items as $item)
                <option  value="{{ $item->name }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label for="">food 2</label>
        <select id="food2" name="food2" class="js-example-basic-single" style="width: 100%;">
            @foreach ($items as $item)
                <option id="{{ $item->name }}" value="{{ $item->name }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

in this solution you should handle  rebuild list from back-end side.
ajax send selected parameter to server and get list of new data then rebuild select options.
for security issue i use post in ajax

Comment: Your approach is correct but it doesn't handle rebuilding the list of models when you change the first select. You should also include an axios call to api to fetch the data again.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AJAX here.

- Call using ajax on change of first drop-down
- In Ajax, send value of selected item
- In Backend, Return all the items from database except that selected value
- And now using javascript/jQuery, update the second drop-down list.